# Magento 2.3.4 - Missing records in the Content->Design->Configuration

Tags: magento2, php, design, favicons

Magento 2.3.4 - Missing records in the `Content->Design->Configuration`

[image: We couldnt find any records]

Can't add favicon in the Magento2.

In `Admin panel -> Content -> Design -> Configuration`.

Shows We couldn't found any records

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First take a back this **design_config_grid_flat** table

Now clear table data

```
TRUNCATE TABLE design_config_grid_flat;
```

Now insert data

```
INSERT INTO 'design_config_grid_flat' ('entity_id', 'store_website_id', 'store_group_id', 'store_id', 'theme_theme_id') VALUES
(0, ZERO, ZERO, ZERO, '3'),
(1, 1, ZERO, ZERO, '3'),
(2, 1, 1, 1, '3');
```

Now run this command

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

Now check it.

Comment: Let me inform above SQL Queries are works for you ??

Comment: SQL Queries are fine. Still it repeats the same "We couldn't find any records".

Comment: After I did setup:upgrade the design configurations are correctly fetched from the database.

Comment: @Sathya I add that in answer