# Magento2 Content -> Design -> Configuration Tables are empty

Tags: theme, design, parent-child-theme, magento2.3.4

I am using Magento-2.3.4 and came to the page to change the theme and I saw only the empty tables.

I looked for answers and they said `allow_url_fopen` to be on but it is already on.

What should I do now to get the table values back here?

[image: empty tables in design configuration page]

Comment: please refer to this [link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/303617/magento-2-3-4-missing-records-in-the-content-design-configuration/303792#303792). I hope this helps.